# Can't upload a file to my webserver, permission error

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ghost-blog

I am running [Ghost](https://ghost.org/) and when I upload a theme through the admin portal, I get this error:

```
EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/my.website/content/themes/London-master'
```

I am sure this is a permission error, but I have been searching for a while on how to fix it.
The user that runs the ghost program is `ghost_server_user` and I am using Ubuntu 20.04 Server.

Edit: I have full root access on the machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Ghost documentation, you have to configure correct permission for the Ghost installation directory. Ghost should not be installed as the root user.

Try to set correct permission for the folders again.

```
# Set directory owner: Replace <user> with the name of your user
sudo chown <user>:<user> /var/www/sitename

# Set the correct permissions
sudo chmod 775 /var/www/sitename
```